How can I get this additional aggregate for ContactCd to work correctly in my bigger query?
I am trying to incorporate so that each ContactCd does not create a new row. I don't know how to make my example less complex. If I dumb it down won't it take out all the joins that are necessary for my query?
   SELECT        
jobNew_HeaderFile.JobCd, 
GRP = max( case when jobCtrl_Rollup.RollupCatCd = 'GRP' then jobCtrl_Rollup.RollupCd end ), 
REG = max( case when jobCtrl_Rollup.RollupCatCd = 'REG' then jobCtrl_Rollup.RollupCd end ), 
' ' AS 'JOB_1', 
' ' AS 'FIELD OPS MANAGER', 
' ' AS 'NATIONAL OPS MANAGER', 
DIV = max( case when jobCtrl_Rollup.RollupCatCd = 'DIV' then jobCtrl_Rollup.RollupCd end ), 
jobCtrl_Company.Company, 
jobNew_HeaderFile.JobName AS LOCATION, 
jobNew_SiteDetail.JobAddr1 AS Addr1, 
jobNew_SiteDetail.JobAddr2 AS Addr2, 
jobNew_SiteDetail.JobCity AS City, 
jobNew_SiteDetail.JobState AS State, 
jobNew_SiteDetail.JobZip1 AS Zip, 
jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts.ContactCd,
jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts.FirstName AS FNAME1, 
jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts.LastName AS LNAME1, 
jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts.Title AS TITLE1, 
jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts.FirstName AS FNAME2, 
jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts.LastName AS LNAME2, 
jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts.Title AS TITLE2,
jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts.FirstName AS FNAME3, 
jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts.LastName AS LNAME3, 
jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts.Title AS TITLE3,
jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts.Phone_wk, 
jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts.Phone_cell, 
jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts.email AS Email, 
jobNew_SiteDetail.ICCPhone AS ICC_Phone, 
jobNew_SiteDetail.ICCPhoneNote AS ICC_Phone_Note, 
jobNew_SiteDetail.Email AS ICC_Email, 
mstClients.ClientCd, 
mstClients.ClientName, 
jobCtrl_Rollup.RollupCatCd, 
jobCtrl_Rollup.RollupCd

FROM jobNew_HeaderFile 
INNER JOIN jobNew_SiteDetail ON jobNew_HeaderFile.JobCd = jobNew_SiteDetail.JobCd 
INNER JOIN jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts ON jobNew_HeaderFile.JobCd = jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts.JobCd 
INNER JOIN jobCtrl_Company ON jobNew_HeaderFile.JobCd = jobCtrl_Company.JobCd 
INNER JOIN mstClients ON jobNew_SiteDetail.ClientCd = mstClients.ClientCd 
INNER JOIN jobCtrl_Rollup ON jobNew_HeaderFile.JobCd = jobCtrl_Rollup.JobCd

WHERE 
jobNew_HeaderFile.JobCd = 990
--AND jobNew_SiteDetail.ActiveStatus = '1'
AND jobCtrl_Rollup.CurrentYN = '1'

GROUP BY
jobNew_HeaderFile.JobCd, 
jobCtrl_Company.Company, 
jobNew_HeaderFile.JobName, 
jobNew_SiteDetail.JobAddr1, 
jobNew_SiteDetail.JobAddr2, 
jobNew_SiteDetail.JobCity, 
jobNew_SiteDetail.JobState, 
jobNew_SiteDetail.JobZip1, 
jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts.ContactCd,
jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts.FirstName, 
jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts.LastName, 
jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts.Title, 
jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts.Phone_wk, 
jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts.Phone_cell, 
jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts.email, 
jobNew_SiteDetail.ICCPhone, 
jobNew_SiteDetail.ICCPhoneNote, 
jobNew_SiteDetail.Email, 
mstClients.ClientCd, 
mstClients.ClientName, 
jobCtrl_Rollup.RollupCatCd, 
jobCtrl_Rollup.RollupCd

The AGGREGATE I was attempting to include is:
Select JobCd
      ,FName1 = max( case when RN=1 then FName end)
      ,LName1 = max( case when RN=1 then LName end)
      ,FName2 = max( case when RN=2 then FName end)
      ,LName2 = max( case when RN=2 then LName end)
      ,FName3 = max( case when RN=3 then FName end)
      ,LName3 = max( case when RN=3 then LName end)
 From ( 
        Select JobCd
              ,RN    = row_number() over (partition by JobCd order by [ContactCd])
              ,FName = parsename(replace([FirstName],' ','.'),1)
              ,LName = parsename(replace([LastName],' ','.'),1)
         From  jobNew_SiteDetail_Contacts
      ) A

     Group By JobCd

Desired result:



JobCd
FName1
LName1
FName2
LName2
FName3
LName3




990
Becky
Smith
Jeffrey
Mason
Christian
Faultenberger




I would suggest a subquery or a CTE to generate the FName#, LName# from the contacts table and then JOIN the results.    A smaller/more focused sample dataset would be more helpful.

Just an aside,  LName and FName would be the same value.   You have parsename( ...,1) for both columns.   I suspect one or the other should be parsename( ... , 2)

Please advise in regards to smaller/more focused.  I pulled a single JobCd and provided all the columns to be accurate, if there needs to be less column I can do that.  Thanks!!

Please provide a [mre] with both sample data and desired results, emphasis on minimal i.e. cut the example down to the simplest case the expresses your problem i.e. we don't need to see 50 unrelated production columns.

I appreciate the replies, and I apologize for wasting your time.   I thought with all the joins the columns would be necessary.  Please close this question, it took me a week to figure out how to even ask the question.  Thanks again.

Does my question somehow need improving, or did I just provide too much data?

This is impossible to answer, for example, we don't know what are the relations between the Job table and the rest. Is it 1-many etc.
But why not do the aggregation you need first, and then join rest of the tables again? This would simplify your query.
Something like:
select * from (
   select ID, MAX(...) from
   Sometable GROUP BY ID
  ) x
INNER JOIN SomeDetails sd
   ON sd.ID = x.ID 
INNER JOIN SomeMoreDetails sd2 ON sd2.ID = x.ID`
... rince and repeat

This way you don't need to aggregate a billion fields.
Also, your query example has:
jobNew_HeaderFile.JobName AS LOCATION,  jobNew_SiteDetail.JobAddr1 AS Addr1,  jobNew_SiteDetail.JobAddr2 AS Addr2,  jobNew_SiteDetail.JobCity AS City,  jobNew_SiteDetail.JobState AS State,  jobNew_SiteDetail.JobZip1 AS Zip, 
Do you think you have to specify all the columns in the question? In my opinion, your question would be much easier if it was only:
jobNew_HeaderFile.JobName AS LOCATION
Further with meaningful short aliases its much easier to read e.g.
jobNew_SiteDetail.JobAddr1 AS Addr1, 
jobNew_SiteDetail.JobAddr2 AS Addr2, 
jobNew_SiteDetail.JobCity AS City, 
jobNew_SiteDetail.JobState AS State, 
jobNew_SiteDetail.JobZip1 AS Zip, 

becomes with alias jsd (JobSiteDetail)
jsd.JobAddr1 AS Addr1, 
jsd.JobAddr2 AS Addr2, 
jsd.JobCity AS City, 
jsd.JobState AS State, 
jsd.JobZip1 AS Zip, 


I honestly feel like I am not knowledgeable enough to really ask the question properly.  It took me a week to figure out my original question.  I am "good enough" with SQL to query, and I am probably trying to do a little more than I should with this one.  thanks for the reply, I will see if I can figure that out.

Your question is fine, but it's hard to answer because people don't sit in front of your computer and can run the query itself. This is why usually a MRE (minumum reproduceable example) is very nice, you write some create tables and some inserts and then it's possible to run things locally

thanks again.  I will work on that for future reference, not that I will make this mistake again.  I am still trying to figure out Dale K comment about wiki and downvotes.

@ChrisKessler its not a complete answer, more of a suggested approach with some hints... too big for comments, but doesn't solve your issue by itself. Which is I assume why Siggemannen made it a wiki - i.e. its not his answer so any votes (up or down) won't go to him.
